# Correct handling of Multiple instances of Interop.Excel in VB .NET

Tags: excel, vb.net, visual-studio-2015, com-interop, excel-interop

My application requires a single Excel to be read by, lets say, 2 different functions within a class.

I have one to read the headings and save them to a .txt file, one to read the data and put it into my DataGridView

As far as I'm aware Interop.Excel is the best way to handle the excel file I will open in my program but unfortunately I'm left with some rather length repetitive code.

Each class at the moment contains the following code:

```
Dim exApp = New Excel.Application
        Dim exWB = exApp.Workbooks.Open(myFilePath)
        Dim exWS = exWB.Sheets(1)
        ** Some statements run here **
        exApp.Quit()
        exApp = Nothing
        exWB = Nothing
```

Not much of a problem if I only have two functions but if I had like 5, this seems like a lengthy way to keep opening and closing the Excel Object.

What would be the best or more efficient way of handling the excel object to be used rather than closed and reopened?

I have tried initialising the Excel object in the class I'm using but I get an error when trying to close it from a function saying it's not allowed.
I also tried to create a CloseExcel() function which is passed ByRef the excel object to be closed, but I get the same error.

Any thoughts or discussions would be appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: "I get an error" is not an appropriate problem description.

Answer (score 0):

It is much more complicated of how you are describing it.
I can give you some general points how to should write your application:

Create a wrapper class ExcelWrapper for example that will be the only class that will deal with excel. The other classes (for example the class in the business layer) will instantiate an object of type ExcelWrapper (not Excel).

This class will:

- instantiate the excel.application object in the constructor
- Have a method that read from the excel all what you need and returns the data to whoever call it. You could return a DataTable for example to populate the datagridview.
- Have another method to read the header and return the info as string (depending of what is written in the header)
- A close excel method to close the opened documents and the application
- You need to implement IDisposable pattern in order to properly clean interop excel objects ,GC cannot do it since it is a unmanaged code.

For each one of the above items, you can find lot of examples in the internet.